# Protractor HTTP GET request

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

In my protractor tests, I'm trying to hit an endpoint that will reset all data for the currently logged in user.  Right now, I'm using plain old javascript to hit that endpoint in a `beforeAll`, and it's successfully hitting it, however now my tests are executing before the page has refreshed causes them to fail.  Here's my current code:

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions,
    el = element(by.css('body div.modal-x'));

browser.executeAsyncScript(function() {
    var inj = angular.element(document.body).injector();
    var reHTTP = inj.get('reHTTP');
    var myService = inj.get('myService');
    var someVar = myService.getCurrent().definition.userName;
    console.log(someVar); // works
    reHTTP.get('/app/' + someVar + '/reset').then(function () {
        // console.log('i am here'); // this works
        // alert('Success!'); // this works
        return browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(el)); // this does not work
    });
});
```

**Problem:** I can't use Protractor functions within that executeScript block because I'm in the browser context now.  i.e. `EC` is undefined

**Question:** How can I properly access/use my `ExpectedConditions` while also hitting this endpoint (again, I'm currently using this function in a `beforeAll` block)?

A few things to note:

- If I don't use `browser.executeAsyncScript` then `angular` is undefined and I can't access the services (or I couldn't find another way)
- Using `executeScript` (rather than AsyncScript) fails even faster than async script

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method `executeAsyncScript` is expecting a callback function to be called. You could call it once the request returns a result:

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions,
    el = element(by.css('body div.modal-x'));

browser.executeAsyncScript(function(callback) {
    var inj = angular.element(document.body).injector();
    var reHTTP = inj.get('reHTTP');
    var myService = inj.get('myService');
    var someVar = myService.getCurrent().definition.userName;
    console.log(someVar); // works
    reHTTP.get('/app/' + someVar + '/reset').then(function () {
        callback();
    });
});
browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(el));
```

Comment: Wow thank you! It was so simple but for some reason I was confusing myself with callbacks.  I had tried it before posting the question but I must not have implemented it right... I think I was confused if `reHTTP` needed it's own callback to call the higher-order one.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

We use a rest call in our `beforeEach` and `afterEach` as well.  Use `browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;` at the beginning of your `beforeAll` function to break out of the angular synchronization, and then after the script, make sure you reset `browser.ignoreSynchronization = false;`.

For example:

```
beforeEach(function() {
    browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
    browser.executeAsyncScript();
    browser.ignoreSynchronization = false;
});
```